# Python Google Calendar sort by date

Tags: python, time, google-api, google-calendar-api

I've got a script that grabs every event off of a Google Claendar, and the searches through those events, and prints the ones that contain a search term to a file.

The problem I'm having is that I need them to be put in order by date, and this doesn't seem to do that.

```
while True:
    events = calendar_acc.events().list(calendarId='myCal',pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for event in events['items']:
        if 'Search Term' in event['summary']: 
        #assign names to hit, and date
        find = event['summary']
        date = event['start'][u'dateTime']

    #only print the first ten digits of the date.

    month = date[5:7]
    day = date[8:10]
    year = date[0:4]
    formatted_date = month+"/"+day+"/"+year
    #write a line
    messy.write(formatted_date+" "+event['summary']+"\n\n")
```

I think there is a way to do this with the `time` module maybe, but I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Without digging into it too much, I've used `dateutil.parser.parse(event['start']['dateTime'])` to parse GCal API output (from the [dateutil package](http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html))

Comment: I see how you would use `dateutil` to parse the `dateTime`. But I dont know how to sort it, once I've gotten that far.

Comment: If you have a list `lst` of parsed event times (they should be `datetime.datetime` objects), you can just sort them using `sorted(lst)` or `lst.sort()`

Comment: OKay, Ive got a sorted list of dates now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Answered my own question in case someone needs the same thing. Thanks again for the help jedwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone else needs to do this. With the help of jedwards.

I ended up creating an empty list: `hits`
And then appending the `['start']['dateTime']` as an `datetime.datetime` object,
and `['summary']` to the list for each event that contained my `"Search Term"`. Like so:

```
hits = []
while True:
    events = calendar_acc.events().list(calendarId='My_Calendar_ID', pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for event in events['items']:
        if "Search Term" in event['summary']: 
           hits.append((dateutil.parser.parse(event['start']['dateTime']), event['summary']))

    page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
    if not page_token:
        break
```

The you just sort the list, and in my case, I cut the `datetime` object down to just be the date. And then wrote the whole line to a file. But this code just prints it to the console.

```
hits.sort()

for x in hits:
    d = x[0]
    date = "%d/%d/%d"%(getattr(d,'month'),getattr(d,'day'), getattr(d,'year'))
    final = str(date)+"\t\t"+str(x[1])

    print final
```

Thanks again to jedwards in the comments!

Comment: I edited your answer to fix indentation (I think), if you could ensure that the indentation is correct, that'd be helpful for people coming in the future.  Also, nice work figuring it out, and thanks so much for posting your solution!

Comment: And if you wanted to go crazy with it, you could change `for x in hits:` to `for (d,s) in hits:`, remove `d=x[0]` and change `str(x[1])` to `str(s)` :)

Answer (score 0):

You can return a sorted list (by date ascending) from the API by using the "orderBy" parameter and setting it to "updated".

```
page_token = None
while True:
    events = service.events().list(calendarId=myID, orderBy='updated', pageToken=page_token).execute()
    for event in events['items']:
        print(event)
        page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
    if not page_token:
        break
```

For more information see: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list

Hope this helps.